# ActionMailer not working on localhost with gmail or google apps for Rails 3.1.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, smtp

I'm using sendgrid on heroku to send email in production, but would like to send email locally on my mac.

I've configured my development.rb a million different ways and keep getting
"Net::SMTPFatalError: 550 Cannot receive from specified address : Unauthenticated senders not allowed"

Spefically, I tried 
varying authentication b/w :plain and :login,
tried using my gmail account credentials,
tried using my google app account credentials.

Nothing seems to work, thoughts?

```
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true  
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
      :address        => 'smtp.gmail.com',
      :domain         => 'somedomain.com',
      :port           => 587,
      :user_name      => 'username@somedomain.com',
      :password       => 'somepassword',
      :authentication => :plain,
      :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

**I thought I had set the in the production settings (production.rb), it turns out I had set them in environment.rb. Removed it there and everything started working.**

Comment: Are you on a Mac, Windows, etc?

Comment: yes, I thought I had set the in the production settings (production.rb), it turns out I had set them in environment.rb. Removed it there and everything started working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had set the mail settings by accident in the Environment.rb so it was overriding anything I was doing at the production/development config level.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try this?

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }

ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {  
  :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",  
  :port                 => 587,  
  :domain               => "gmail.com",  
  :user_name            => "email@gmail.com",  
  :password             => "password",  
  :authentication       => "plain",
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```